# .php and .onion will not work

Tags: onion-routing

When I type in URLs directly the page will not be found. I understand that sites often get taken offline, but not a single site has worked for me (out of at least 40). Using any words such as "onion site", Google will refuse to load the page stating "Error 403 (Forbidden)!!". My clock and date settings are updated, I'm using their recommended bridge,and Firefox Connection Settings is using SOCKS v5. Can someone recommend me a fix? I'm using Windows 8, Thanks!

Comment: I just want to say: `.php` is a [filename extension;](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Filename_extension) `.onion` is a [TLD.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Top-level_domain) :-)

Comment: What browser do you use? Does https://facebookcorewwwi.onion/ work for you?

Comment: I'm using Firefox, and yes that site does work for me. What does that mean though?

Comment: It means that you've connected to the Tor network successfully. The only problem is that you're trying to access hidden services that no longer exist. Yes, all 40 of them.

Comment: Some sites that share onion sites are available using chrome, but Tor will not allow the websites due to key words like onion, or deep web

Comment: It's incredibly unlikely that Tor is blocking certain websites due to keywords.  What leads you to believe that?  Also, `.onion` sites are *only* accessible over Tor.